# Dual boot install corrupted OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently did a dual boot install of Xubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome, both 16.04.

I first installed Xubuntu using "something else" option, and created a partion or 150gb out of 300 and installed to it. Xubuntu ran fine.

I then did the same steps for Ubuntu gnome, with a partion of 40gb on the remaining space.

I then booted to gnome and played around in there very minimally.

Then when I booted up to ubuntu, the desktop was corrupted. The boot screen background was black, instead of the boot screen background image. Then when I logged in to the desktop, all of the desktop icons were missing with generic white icons with a red X on them.

I am somewhat new to linux, and I have no clue where to go from here. Is it possible that the HD is just corrupted, and it has nothing to do with my dual boot installation?

Comment: xubuntu & ubuntu-gnome are almost the same;  so in my opinion they are not worth dual boot.  i'd install one, then install the other desktop ONTO your existing install - so you select XUBUNTU or UBUNTU-GNOME at the login screen; both using the same fs (filesystems) and update together.  as for your problems; I don't know.  I'd suggest provide more info such as your partition info (run `blkid`, `sudo fdisk -l` etc) and add that info to your screen.  i'm not very familiar with ubuntu-gnome (don't use it) so don't know if it clobbers any xfce info; but doubt it.

Comment: Xubuntu is my main OS install. And the other space is for audition other distros without touching my main install. Thanks for the info, I will update my question asap.

Comment: Check your drive's S.M.A.R.T.